# Не работает запрос при использовании LINQ Method Syntax

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

Начал изучать Entity Framework Core и, соответственно, LINQ. Но столкнулся с такой проблемой: у меня есть 2 таблицы: **`Table`** с полями `Id`, `Name` и `CategoryId`(что является foreign key к следующей таблице), и **`Category`** с полями `Id` и `Name`.

При использовании LINQ Query Syntax - запрос отрабатывается правильно, возвращая нужные данные. При использовании же LINQ Method Syntax, не возвращается ничего. Какую ошибку я допустил в этом коде?

```
//Select objects that have "Breakfast" category + LINQ Method Syntax
Category category = context.Category.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Name == "Breakfast");
List<Table> tables = category.Table.ToList();
tables.ForEach(r => Console.WriteLine(r.Name)); //Returns nothing (tables.Count == 0) - ERROR

//Select objects that have "Breakfast" category + LINQ Query Syntax
var tablesQuery = (from t in context.Table
                   where t.Category.Name == "Breakfast"
                   select t).ToList();
tablesQuery.ForEach(t  => Console.WriteLine((t as Table).Name)); //Returns proper data (tables.Count == 2) - CORRECT
```

Comment: `что является foreign key к следующей бд` вы путаете таблицу и базу данных.

Comment: ваши запросы не эквивалентны. Попробуйте `var tables = context.Tables.Where(t=>t.Category.Name == "Breakfast").ToList();`

Comment: спасибо, исправил

Comment: Если вы хотите починить свой звпрос, то вам надо загружать зависимости, типа так `Category category = context.Category.Include(x=>x.Table).FirstOrDefault(c => c.Name == "Breakfast");`

Comment: @tym32167  Действительно работает, спасибо большое.
Не могли бы вы подробнее объяснить, в чем у меня проблема?

Comment: У вас проблема в том, что вы когда грузите Категории, думаете, что с категориями грузится и связанная таблица `category.Table`, но это не так. Вам надо явно сказать, мол, уважаемый EFCore, когда будете из БД тянуть категории, захватите оттуда и связанную `category.Table`. Чтобы это указать, есть спец метод `Include`, например вот тут `Category category = context.Category.Include(x=>x.Table).FirstOrDefault(c => c.Name == "Breakfast");` вы видите, что я сначала обращаюсь к категориям, и сразу прошу подтянуть таблицу `.Include(x=>x.Table)`, и после уже делаю выборку.

Comment: Но вообще, когда вам надо получить таблицу из БД, вам будет проще сразу её и запрашивать вот так `var tables = context.Tables.Where(t=>t.Category.Name == "Breakfast").ToList();`, тут вам даже категории в память грузить не надо.

Comment: @tym32167 Ещё раз спасибо большое! Вы очень помогли.

Comment: пожалуйста, на здоровье.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У вас проблема в том, что вы когда грузите Категории, думаете, что с категориями грузится и связанная таблица `category.Table`, но это не так. Вам надо явно сказать, мол, уважаемый EFCore, когда будете из БД тянуть категории, захватите оттуда и связанную `category.Table`. Чтобы это указать, есть спец метод `Include`, например вот тут

```
Category category = context.Category
                 .Include(x=>x.Table)
                 .FirstOrDefault(c => c.Name == "Breakfast");
```

вы видите, что я сначала обращаюсь к категориям, и сразу прошу подтянуть таблицу `.Include(x=>x.Table)`, и после уже делаю выборку.

Но вообще, когда вам надо получить таблицу из БД, вам будет проще сразу её и запрашивать вот так

```
var tables = context.Tables.Where(t=>t.Category.Name == "Breakfast").ToList();
```

тут вам даже категории в память грузить не надо.